# Tell ActivityIndicator to show yourself and then navigate to another page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

On **Xamarin.Forms** Project, I am trying to tell`ActivityIndicator` to show yourself and then navigate to another page

```
activityIndicatorObject = new ActivityIndicator()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    Color = Color.Red,
                    IsVisible = false,
                    IsRunning = false,
                    IsEnabled = false,
                    BindingContext = this,
                };
ViewBookButton = new Button{ Text = "view book" };
ViewBookButton.Clicked += ViewBook;
protected void ViewBook(Object sender,EventArgs e)
            {
                //Go To View Book Page 
                activityIndicatorObject .IsVisible = true;
                activityIndicatorObject .IsRunning = true;
                activityIndicatorObject .IsEnabled = true;
                activityIndicatorObject .SetBinding(ActivityIndicator.IsVisibleProperty, "IsBusy");
                this.IsBusy = true;
                Navigation.PushAsync(new BookPage());
                this.IsBusy = false;
            }
```

`ActivityIndicator` doesn't showing? How I can make it showing?

Comment: Its worth noting because you are loading a new page which will be done on the `UI Thread` this loading will block the `UI Thread` meaning that even if you did get an activity indicator to show It wont spin because the `UI Thread` will be blocked by the page loading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand you tell `ActivityIndicator` show yourself and then navigate to another page. And new page hasn't own `ActivityIndicator`. I would like to suggest you make your hard operations in `OnAppearing` method of `BookPage`.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    activityIndicator.IsVisible = true;

    // Some hard operations

    activityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
}
```

Or use binding instead of `activityIndicator.IsVisible = true;`

Comment: Agreed that it's better to show the ActivityIndicator on the "new" page. Better pushing the new page directly and show loading there, rather than having a page pushing at an undefined time. It would be misleading for the user and could give you timing-based errors that are hard to investigate. Generally, try to react to user input as fast as possible - don't wait for any asynchrone operation.